# How Can I pause speak command in vbscript? I have to play it from the same paused position

Tags: vbscript

1. How Can I pause speak command in vbscript? I have to play it from the same paused position.
2. Code block:

   ```
   Dim Speak, Path
   Path = "string"
   Path = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\TheReunion.txt"
   const ForReading = 1
   Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(Path,ForReading)
   strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
   Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
   Speak.Speak strFileText
   objFileToRead.Close
   Set objFileToRead = Nothing
   ```

Comment: If you want to do something in VBScript then tag it as VBScript only. Don't try to trick people into viewing your question by tagging it with irrelevant languages.

Comment: What about [pause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723604(v=vs.85).aspx) and [resume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723607(v=vs.85).aspx) methods?

Comment: Thanks @LotPings

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `speak` method **asynchronously** before using the `pause` and `resume` methods as mentioned by LotPings in the comments.

Code:

```
Dim Speak, Path
Path = "string"
Path = "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\TheReunion.txt"
const ForReading = 1
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(Path,ForReading)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
Speak.Speak strFileText,1                          '1=Asynchronous. Click the link below for other possible values "SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags"

'Due to async call to speak method, we can proceed with the code execution while the voice is being played in the background. Now we can call pause and resume methods
wscript.sleep 5000                 'voice played for 5000ms
Speak.pause                        'paused
wscript.sleep 4000                 'remains paused for 4000ms 
Speak.resume                       'resumes 
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing
```

[SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720892(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Intrigue in this led me to take inspiration from *Kira's* answer and develop it somewhat (in a bad, novice kind of way), to achieve the pause/resume objective interactively, the code below works for me, and hopefully it's of some help to you...

```
option explicit
dim strpath, fso, strfile, strtxt, user, voice, flag

flag = 2

call init
sub init
do while len(strpath) = 0
strpath = inputbox ("Please enter the full path of txt file", "Txt to Speech")
if isempty(strpath) then
wscript.quit()
end if
loop
'strpath = "C:\Users\???\Desktop\???.txt"

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
on error resume next
set strfile = fso.opentextfile(strpath,1)
if err.number = 0 then
strtxt = strfile.readall()
strfile.close
call ctrl
else
wscript.echo "Error: " & err.number & vbcrlf & "Source: " & err.source & vbcrlf &_
"Description: " & err.description
err.clear
call init
end if
end sub

sub ctrl
user = msgbox("Press ""OK"" to Play / Pause", vbokcancel + vbexclamation, "Txt to Speech")
select case user
case vbok
    if flag = 0 then
        voice.pause
        flag = 1
        call ctrl
    elseif flag = 1 then
        voice.resume
        flag = 0
        call ctrl
    else
        call spk
    end if
case vbcancel
    wscript.quit
end select
end sub 

sub spk
'wscript.echo strtxt
set voice = createobject("sapi.spvoice")
voice.speak strtxt,1
flag = 0
call ctrl
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Albert Fitzwilliam Digby